# How to detect that F# program is compiled on Mono?

Tags: compilation, f#, mono, preprocessor

I am trying to make some F# code conditional based on compile-time environment and can't find any OS-specific definitions that F# compiler would recognise. #if MONO doesn't work. Is there any way to detect OS at compile-time for F#?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think there is any out-of-the box way of doing this. You will need to define your own symbol such as `MONO` and call the compiler with `--define:MONO` when building the Mono version.

That said, I would be a bit careful about this - there is no clear concept of "compiled for Mono" in F# and .NET. When you compile F# code, you always get a `dll` or `exe` that you can run anywhere and nothing prevents you from copying one build output and running it in another environment.

There is a standard way of detecting where the program is running *at runtime* using:

```
Type.GetType("Mono.Runtime") != null
```

You might have good reasons for wanting two separate builds, but it might be worth considering whether you can just make the appropriate choices at runtime (that probably does not work if you rely on some Windows-specific libraries such as WinForms charting).

Comment: Thank you Tomas. I agree that it's a bad sign if an F# program uses conditional OS compilation. There reason I wanted to try this because I couldn't get to work __SOURCE_DIRECTORY__ definition on Mac, so I wanted to try a workaround with preprocessor directive.

Comment: @VagifAbilov What problems were you getting into with `__SOURCE_DIRECTORY__`? This is more useful in scripts though - I would not use that in compiled code (typically, you'll want a directory relative to where the application runs, not to where it was compiled - and you can get that via currently executing assembly).

Comment: @TomasPerticek It is because of F# SQLProvider I am using __SOURCE_DIRECTORY__. We recently added support for offline schema in SQLProvider and now it supports referencing serialized schema, so I had a setting ContextSchemaPath=__SOURCE_DIRECTORY__ + ".some file" that was used only at compilation time. But on Mac it didn't point to right location so I was trying to resolve it using #ifdef.

Comment: @VagifAbilov That makes sense! In that case, I completely understand that you need this at compile-time. I guess it would be good to find the root cause - was the type provider getting a valid path?

Comment: The type provider is getting correct path on Windows but not on Mac. But if I send an absolute path (without SOURCE_DIRECTORY) on Mac then it works. So the provider itself works on both platforms, it's just SOURCE_DIRECTORY that is not correctly set on Mac (it seems). I am far from my Mac right now but will test more when I am at home.